# How to access frames using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to access information on a website that uses frames. When I try to access the site I get the website source, but I also get the `This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.` I would've assumed that I needed to leave this page open though in order to access the frames. So what I've done is create a new object to make a request to the page with the frames. However, that returns a page that redirects to an error.

My question is if it's possible to get the frame information using HttpWebRequest and is there a tutorial or an example online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You need to match request that browser makes to retrieve these frames (potentially faking referrer and other headers).

Use some HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see requests your code generates and compare your requests to browser's ones.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. All I ended up doing was adding the link of the source page as the referrer and the link to the frames as the address.